# Colocar texto dentro das categorias e inverter ordem do eixo

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com duas dúvidas. A primeira seria uma forma dos números ficarem alocados nas suas respectivas categorias. A outra seria inverter os anos do eixo X, de maneira que fique em ordem crescente.

Meu código:

```
ggplot(dados_aids, aes(x= Ano, y = Taxa)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = raca)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Taxa)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 years", date_labels = "%Y") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Procure limitar uma dúvida por questão, a não ser que sejam diretamente relacionadas. É mais fácil para quem for tentar responder e para quem consultar o site em busca de soluções.

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte:

```
ggplot(dados_aids, aes(x= Ano, y = Taxa, group = raca)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = raca)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Taxa),position = position_stack()) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 years", date_labels = "%Y") +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Para os rótulos serem posicionados adequadamente, use `position_stack`, com a opção `vjust = .5` se quiser centralizado. Coloque a opção `fill` na estética global, para ser entendida por todas geometrias como a variável de agrupamento (ou mantenha `fill` na estética da `geom_col` e use a opção `group` na global).

Quanto à ordem dos anos, a `scale_*_date` não aceita a opção `trans`. Pode converter o ano para numérico e usar `scale_*_reverse`.

Como não postou seus dados, estou criando um *data.frame* de exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(367)
dados <- data.frame(
  ano = rep(as.Date(paste0(2011:2020, "-07-01")), each = 4),
  grupo = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 10),
  valor = sample(2:50, 40))

dados$ano <- as.numeric(format(dados$ano, "%Y"))

ggplot(dados, aes(x = ano, y = valor, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = valor), position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = unique(dados$ano)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]