# Como adicionar valores dentro das barras no ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
    
dados %>%
      filter( Sexo != "Ignorado" & trimestre ==  "Mar-Abr-Mai, 20") %>%
      ggplot() +
      aes(x = Sexo, fill = `Faixa etária`) +
      geom_bar() +
      ylim(0, maximo.sex)+
      geom_text(aes(label = ..count.. [as.character(..x..)]*100), 
                stat = "count", position = position_fill(0.5), family="serif", size=3, color="black") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = met.brewer("NewKingdom", 4)) +
      labs(y = "", subtitle = "Mar-Abr-Mai, 20",
           fill = "Faixa etária"
      ) +
      tema
```

Quando rodo o resultado é o da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria colocar os valores dentro das barras, mas não estou conseguindo com o `geom_text`

Comment: Oi Mariana Costa! A sua pergunta terá mais chance de ser respondida se o código pode ser replicado pelas pessoas que querem te ajudar. Você pode incluir os dado, ou uma parte deles usando o comando na sua tabela `dput(dados)`, `dput(head(dados, n = 20))` ou em dados similares.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Colocar texto dentro das categorias e inverter ordem do eixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/527223/colocar-texto-dentro-das-categorias-e-inverter-ordem-do-eixo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar `stat_count()` para incluir texto de contagens de variáveis discretas ("integers").

No exemplo utilizo os dados "iris" do pacote `datasets`

```
library(ggplot2)

plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, fill =  Species)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'count') +
    stat_count(geom = 'text', color = 'white',
               aes(label = ..count..),
               position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou. Mt obg!!